# Ubuntu Community Appreciation Day

Tags: discussion

*Though this should have been set by the moderators, I like to appreciate all people by making this meta question*

Today is November 2012, and it's Ubuntu Community Appreciation Day!

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UCADay for details.

```
Ubuntu is not just an Operating System, it is a whole community in which everybody
collaborates with everybody to bring to the life a wonderful Human experience. When you
download the iso, burn it, install it and start to enjoy it, you know that a lot of 
people made magnificent efforts to deliver the best Ubuntu OS possible.

For all the effort exerted, for every minute of the year, some gave of their time 
talent or treasure. There's the Ubuntu Community Apreciation Day, when everybody --
whether user, developer, or non-developer contributor anyone who gives a hand making
Ubuntu what it is today -- everybody takes a moment to thank someone for their
contribution. Every contribution counts! Take time to say, "Thank you!"
```

So what can you do then in this day in AskUbuntu?

First of all, if you thought you have some questions answered but you haven't marked it as answer or upvoted, do so. It's a better way to get the answerer warmth inside his heart that he has made Ubuntu ever so slightly better.

Secondly, you can go to the chatroom in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room (if you have enough rep) to thank the people, especially the moderators.

The moderators have been very busy keeping this site running, and I'd like to thank @Oli, @MarcoCeppi, @jrg, @fossfreedom, @BrunoPereria, @StefanoPalazzo for their hard-working support to make this website the best as it can be.

Thirdly, try posting on social websites about UCADay and thank the guys who helped you there. Quite a good channel to do some thanksgiving~

Finally, let me thank everybody who have either asked or answered a question here at AskUbuntu. You guys rock!!!